# <abbr> plugin for Redactor

Tags: redactor

I'm attempting to write a basic plugin for Redactor (Redactor plugin on Craft 3 RC) but I'm tripping at the first hurdle:

It seems I can add any attribute to my `<abbr>` other than a `title` (the only attribute I need!). Here is my code so far:

```
(function($)
{
    $.Redactor.prototype.abbr = function()
    {
        return {
            init: function ()
            {
                var button = this.button.add('abbr', 'Abbreviation');
                this.button.setIcon(button, '<i class="re-icon-toggle"></i>');                
                this.button.addCallback(button, function()
                {
                    this.inline.format('abbr', 'title', 'test');
                });
            }
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It wraps the selected text in `<abbr>` but fails to add the title attribute. Other attribute types, such as `class` work fine:

`this.inline.format('abbr', 'class', 'test');`

(In two minds whether to post this here or on SO but as this is for a Craft site...)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn’t have to do with your field’s “HTML Purifier” settings?

Comment: @carics - sorry for the slow response. I've just tried disabling HTML Purifier on that field but it made no difference. Also tried disabling "clean up HTML" but that didn't help.

Comment: that’s not good, because it’s now very likely that it is a bug in the Redactor code itself. I know that they are stripping out / not allowing certain tags or attributes because they are, for example, using them to temporarily store information.

Comment: @carics - it is a bug in redactor itself but it doesn't seem that abbr is being used for anything. It's just not recognised by redactor as in inline tag. I added it to the inlineTags array (line 310 of redactor.js) and it works fine now. I'll send a message to Imperavi.

Comment: Now that you mention that array, I can remember – it is not very complete. Good luck with your support ticket and you can totally add your comment as an official answer!

Answer (score 2):

Digging into Redactor a little deeper I found that it fails to include `<abbr>` in its list of inline tags. To add support I made the following modifications to /lib/radactor/redactor.js:

Line 149:

```
pasteInlineTags: ['br', 'strong', 'ins', 'code', 'del', 'span', 'samp', 'kbd', 'abbr', 'sup', 'sub', 'mark', 'var', 'cite', 'small', 'b', 'u', 'em', 'i'],
```

Line 310:

```
inlineTags: ['a', 'span', 'strong', 'strike', 'b', 'u', 'em', 'i', 'code', 'del', 'ins', 'samp', 'kbd', 'abbr', 'sup', 'sub', 'mark', 'var', 'cite', 'small'],
```

I've made Imperavi aware of the omission so hopefully they'll get this sorted in the next release.

**Update:** Imperavi have sent a response:

> We'll add the abbr support including the paste arrays in the next update.